# Laravel Route Model Binding: Check if a route parameter exists in model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have this route:

```
Route::get('{country}/{federalstate?}/{city?}', ['as' => 'regions.show', 'uses' => 'RegionsController@show']);
```

Next I have a model Country with a few countries in it.

I want this route only to take effect, when given {country} exists in the model Country. I want to do this, because don't wan to use a prefix for that route.

The ugly way would be a regular expression. Ugly, because I would have to update it every time I add a new country to the model.

So what's the best way to accomplish what I want to do?

Maybe this could help -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding - but I am a beginner, and I can't get it to work.

*edit:*

this might work:

```
Route::get('{country?}/{federalstate?}/{city?}', ['as' => 'regions.show', 'uses' => 'RegionsController@show'])->where([
    'country' => 'germany|usa|canada'
]);
```

But, as I said, I would have to change the Regex every time I add a new country to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution for now:

in AppServiceProvider in the boot() method:

```
$available_countries = Country::select('slug')->get();

$available_countries = $available_countries->toArray();

$tmp = array();

foreach ($available_countries as $country)
{
    $tmp[] = $country['slug'];
}

Config::set('app.available_countries', $tmp);
```

and in my routes file:

```
Route::get('{country?}/{federalstate?}/{city?}', ['as' => 'regions', 'uses' => 'RegionsController@index'])->where([
    'country' => implode('|', config('app.available_countries'))
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested, Route-Model binding may be your best bet. You can see from the docs that if the model you've bound to your route does not exist, the route will return a 404.

Just be aware that the default functionality in Route-Model binding expects an ID from the URL. If you want to override that, you can do the following:

```
/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'name';
}
```

Comment: the 404 is the problem :-/ What about myurl.com/somecontroller - the only thing I can think of, is that I set the route I have posted as the last route, but also not very elegant..

Comment: What do you want to happen when a user types a url that starts with a country that doesn't exist?

Comment: As I said I want that route to just be acitve, when the country exists (there is no prefix, the {country} is in the domain root). So when someone visits myurl.com/thiscountrydoesnotexist the route should not be applied.

Comment: 404 is the HTTP code to indicate "Not Found". So when you say "the route should not be applied", you're describing a situation where the server should return a 404. For example, if you go to http://stackoverflow.com/thispagedoesntexist and open your browser console, you'll see that the status code returned is 404.

Comment: When there's no route that fits, of course, there should be a 404. But my route as it is, grabs all requests and gives a 404, also if there may be another route that fits.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you could pass Country to your controller as model. If there is no such model in your DB, Laravel will produce 404 error.

Comment: Is that automatic? Could you please add a `code` example or reference?